# Layers and variables box does not exist in ArcGIS raster calculator window?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster, raster-calculator

I have a problem with layers and variables box in raster calculator.

The layers and variables box does not exist in the raster calculator window!

So I cannot add any raster to the expression.

I am using ArcGIS 10.

What should I exactly do to appear this box in the raster calculator?

Comment: I am having the same problem as Sarah, I have many shapefiles in the table of content but layers and variables are not coming out in the raster calculator window. I followed Aaron's suggestions but nothing still comes out in the raster calculator window. Anybody able to help me? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possible solutions here.  If you see the green point labeled "Map Algebra Expression" in the top left of the window, you are in luck.  Simply place your cursor the left of the Raster Calculator window (a new left-right cursor will appear), drag the window to the left and the variable box should appear.  Another alternative is to drag and drop the raster layer from the table of contents or Catalog directly into the expression box.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I found the source of my big mistake! I was doing spatial analysis on ArcCatolog instead of ArcMap!

Comment: @sara You can also use raster calculator in ArcCatalog--simply drag and drop raster variables into the expression window.  This will input a full pathname rather than a layer name.